# awk if 0 divided by x output 0

Tags: awk

I have `file`

```
chr     gene    start   end     totsites        synWBM  synBF   misWBM  misBF
NC_044998.1     LOC100221041    14582   80739   14237   99      98      284     285
NC_044998.1     DCBLD2  31388   68748   10471   145     149     503     499
NC_044998.1     CMSS1   80874   299341  11061   48      48      179     178
NC_044998.1     FILIP1L 112495  297570  49095   170     173     642     639
NC_044998.1     LOC116808959    287349  289742  3010    0       0       0       0
NC_044998.1     TBC1D23 300404  343805  7190    39      39      153     154
NC_044998.1     NIT2    333622  344667  2828    18      18      63      63
NC_044998.1     TOMM70  346168  368957  4041    27      27      95      95
NC_044998.1     LNP1    371654  380427  2264    27      30      93      90
```

I'm trying to have `$10` be `$6/$5` using

```
awk '$$10 = $6/$5' file
```

but awk wont output the lines for which `$6 = 0`

I would like to have instances where `$6 = 0` as `0`

Comment: `awk '{ print $6/$5 }' file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, In case your Input_file is NOT having 5th field in any line then adding 1 condition here to avoid error of `fatal: division by zero attempted` lets add additional check to avoid this error.

```
awk 'FNR>1 { print $0"\t"($5?$6/$5:"NaN") }' Input_file
```

Comment: In case `$6/$5` has `$5 == 0` the output would be **inf**, which might not be worse than "NA"?

Comment: @e2-e4, if 5th field is `0` then also it gives that this `fatal` error(as well as it covers null value too), if I am understanding your comment here. I changed it to NaN to make it more clear, Not a number(I think this is what they say ) cheers

Comment: Nope. Awk doesn't fatal if div by 0, it sets the result as "inf". Try it. Cheers to you my friend. Nevertheless +1 for the use of the ternary.

Comment: @e2-e4, for my GNU `awk`, if I give a sample line `NC_044998.1     a       1234     0 0 10` it gives me an error saying `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=file1 FNR=11) fatal: division by zero attempted` I had tested it(if I am not wrong here and we are on same page) :) thanks for having good conversation on this one buddy cheers.

Comment: My awk (Ubuntu 18.04.7) is `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan`

Comment: @e2-e4, hhmmm interesting, my sample line gives that error(GNU Awk 4.1.3) and even I try to save it in last field gives an error, may be they would have caught and fixed that issue in `mawk` :) Thanks for letting know, this conversation could help us to know `awk` features better, cheers.

Comment: I guess the problem is that either the numerator or the denominator are 0, I get the error. How can I write this $5?$6/$5:"NaN" to say that if $5 || $6 are 0 do NaN?

Comment: @MadzaFarias-Virgens, no problem will be the later one IMHO, `0/5` is fine but `6/0` is problem for awk that's why this wrapper to keep it away from errors :) cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can do it quite easily by appending `$6/$5` to the end of the record. For example:

```
awk 'FNR>1 { print $0"\t"$6/$5 }' file
```

(`FNR>1` will skip the first row, you can output it with a rule `FNR==1 {print $0}`, or just `FNR==1 {print}` , if you like)

**Example Output**

With your data in `file`, the above would produce:

```
NC_044998.1     LOC100221041    14582   80739   14237   99      98      284     285     0.00695371
NC_044998.1     DCBLD2  31388   68748   10471   145     149     503     499     0.0138478
NC_044998.1     CMSS1   80874   299341  11061   48      48      179     178     0.00433957
NC_044998.1     FILIP1L 112495  297570  49095   170     173     642     639     0.00346267
NC_044998.1     LOC116808959    287349  289742  3010    0       0       0       0       0
NC_044998.1     TBC1D23 300404  343805  7190    39      39      153     154     0.0054242
NC_044998.1     NIT2    333622  344667  2828    18      18      63      63      0.00636492
NC_044998.1     TOMM70  346168  368957  4041    27      27      95      95      0.00668151
NC_044998.1     LNP1    371654  380427  2264    27      30      93      90      0.0119258
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: @DCR Great answer, much better than my comment.

Comment: Your comment was great. It showed exactly what the issue was `"(FILENAME=file FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted"`